# Connecting two points by a line with D3 JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I did a bit of searching and found something close to what i want to achieve but it does not work. Am I doing it the right way ? I have a a plot with two exponential curves and I want to connect the end of the first one to the beginning of the second one.

I have stored my data as follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {


         product.push({ "ID": Number(c[i]), "value1": new Date(v[i]), "value2": new Date(v1[i]) });

         if (i == 0) {
             x1 = (v1[100]) // x value when y value is 100
             y1 = (c[100])
         }
         if (i == 100) {
             x0 = (v[0]) // x value when y value is 0
             y0 = (c[0])
         }
            }
```

I checked the values of x0, x2, y0 and y1 and it seems to store the correct values. To draw the connect line I used the following :

```
      svg.append('line')
.attr('x1', x(function (d) { return x(d.x0); }))
.attr('x2', x(function (d) { return x(d.x1); }))
.attr('y1', y(function (d) { return x(d.y0); }))
.attr('y2', y(function (d) { return x(d.y1); }))
    .style({
        stroke: "#000000"
    });
```

But I cannot seem to connect those two points. Is there any other way ?

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do. In your loop, you push objects onto a `products` array which you then don't use. You also define variables inside the loop that aren't stored anywhere. In the definition of your line, you're referencing data, but never binding any. How are the lines you want to draw defined?

Comment: I am sorry as I did not edit the code before copying it. I just thought over your comment for a while and found the solution. Thanks a lot for guiding.